# php mysqli query statements and checking of affected rows

Tags: php, mysqli

currently i am studying PHP MYSQLi, PDO and still having difficulty with some basic statements also confused.. I'm trying to check if an email is already existing in my database before storing it but it seems my code is not working when i tested it. am i missing something or do i need to revise my code..?

```
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mydbname");

    if (!$mysqli) {
        echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
        echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
        echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
        exit;
    }

    $email="johnsmith@gmail.com";

    $username_query = "SELECT username FROM user WHERE email = ?";
    $statement = $mysqli->prepare($username_query);
    $statement->bind_param('s', $email);

    $statement->execute();
    $statement->store_result();
```

> now, i want to know if a row was affected. There's a record of
>   johnsmith@gmail.com on my database but the result always show 0. 
>   $mysqli->affected_rows wouldn't work for me too.. please enlighten me, thanks.

```
    printf("row affected: %d.\n", $statement->num_rows);
```

Comment: use this `$statement->affected_rows` to get the number of affected rows

Comment: `printf("row affected: %d.\n", $statement->affected_rows);`

Comment: man! i did not see that! it's now working! thanks a lot @dass!

Comment: yet this property can tell the the number of rows returned

Comment: @user1957878 Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 0):

Both `num_rows` and `affected_rows` are the way to get the number of rows found by SELECT query (given the query *indeed found something* and `get_result()/store_result()` were used)

Everyone can run the following code and see

```
$email="johnsmith@gmail.com";

$statement = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT ?");
$statement->bind_param('s', $email);
$statement->execute();
$statement->store_result();

echo "affected_rows: $statement->affected_rows\n";
echo "num_rows: $statement->num_rows\n";
```

thus the question is caused by a mere confusion of some sort.

**So please let's not make it a source for another superstition.**

Answer (score -1):

You need to fetch the result.

After `$statement->store_result();`:

`$statement -> fetch();`